# Express/MySQL not returning same value returned by MySQL Workbench

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, mysql-workbench

I have a query that is perfectly working when I run it on MySQL Workbench, but when I run it on Express it is returning me all the data on my database. Please help fix?
PS. posted this before but didn't get fixed.

--Client

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/filter',
   type: 'get',
   contentType: 'application',
   data: { categoryIDs : checkedCategory,
           materialIDs : checkedMaterial,
           designIDs   : checkedDesign},
   success: function(response) {
      console.log(response.products);
   }
});
```

--Server code

```
getFilteredTable: function(req, res, next) {
   var filter="SELECT COUNT(A.id) \
               FROM tbl_product A JOIN tbl_product_details B ON A.id = B.prod_id  \
               JOIN tbl_category C ON A.id = C.prod_id \
               JOIN tbl_material D ON A.id = D.prod_id \
               JOIN tbl_design E ON A.id = E.prod_id \
               WHERE C.category_id IN (?) \
               AND (D.material_id IN (?) \
               OR E.design_id IN (?))";
   mysqlConnection.query(filter, [req.query.categoryIDs, req.query.materialIDs, req.query.designIDs], function(err, rows, fields) {
      if(!err)
      res.send({products : rows});
      else
      console.log(err);
   });
},
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.id)
FROM tbl_product A 
JOIN tbl_product_details B ON A.id = B.prod_id
JOIN tbl_category C ON A.id = C.prod_id
JOIN tbl_material D ON A.id = D.prod_id
JOIN tbl_design E ON A.id = E.prod_id
WHERE C.category_id IN (6) AND (D.material_id IN (15) OR E.design_id IN (39));
```

I expect the output to be (workbench result):
COUNT(A.id): 42

instead, it's giving me:
COUNT(A.id): 1582

Comment: My guess is that your `WHERE IN` clauses are the problem.  You should try printing the query to the console to see what your JS code is actually running.

Comment: @Barmar It's still giving me 1582. Thanks for that info tho, I updated my query without the DISTINCT.

Comment: When you mix `AND` and `OR` in a conditional expression, it's always a good idea to use parentheses to make sure they're grouped as you intend.

Comment: Tried it too. Workbench returns 42 (with parenthesis) and 687 (without). and JS returns only 1852. This is weird, hope it gives me some type of error so I can figure out what's going on. :(

Comment: There's no reason why an identical query would return different results against the same database. Something has to be different, but you're not seeing it.

Comment: I tried copy-pasting exact query bunch of times now

Comment: The only explanation seems to be that your parameters are not what you think they are. Have you checked their content? You can look at the fully generated query with (e.g.) `var myquery = mysqlConnection.query(filter, [req.qu...  ; console.log(myquery.sql);`