# Alternative way to improve my mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Is there a best way to write this query? It is working just fine on workbench but when I run it on JS, it's not returning the right value.

What I want to do is I want to show users the list of all the items based on their filtered settings (basing on selected category's material and design).

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.id)
FROM tbl_product A 
JOIN tbl_product_details B ON A.id = B.prod_id
JOIN tbl_category C ON A.id = C.prod_id
JOIN tbl_material D ON A.id = D.prod_id
JOIN tbl_design E ON A.id = E.prod_id
WHERE C.category_id IN (6) AND (D.material_id IN (15) OR E.design_id IN (39));
```

[image: db structure looks like this]

I expect the output to be (workbench result):
COUNT(A.id): 42

instead, it's giving me:
COUNT(A.id): 1582

Comment: why have you not included any javascript, if you're having problem `when I run it on JS, it's not returning the right value.`

Comment: Where are your table structures?

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX, I figured that there is nothing wrong with my JS code since all of my other queries work except for this one. Anyways, JS code is on my other question. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55803063/express-mysql-not-returning-same-value-returned-by-mysql-workbench)

Comment: the other question has `SELECT COUNT(A.id)` ... here you have `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(A.id)` ... so ... could that be the difference?

Comment: @JaromandaX, both giving me the same result with or without. I'll edit it to avoid confusion. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.id)
```

There are probably other ways to phrase the query (notably, using `EXISTS`), but this is the simplest modification.